# Best way to save incoming/outgoing emails to MySQL

Tags: mysql, email

What would be the best way to set-up a script which automatically 'monitors' several company (Google Apps) email addresses and copies incoming and outgoing email data into a MySQL database if the email is being sent to/from a recognised address.

To identify recognised addresses, the script would need to query an existing MySQL table to see if a sender/recipient is a known user.  If this is the case, the email content and metadata would be written as a new row in the table.  Attachments would be copied to an FTP server, with the URL of this attachment stored as part of the email data.

If the email is part of a threaded email chain, only the new part of the message should be stored, but the row ID of associated messages should also be stored.

Any thoughts on how this could be possible would be greatly appreciated!  In particular, which programming languages and set-ups could achieve this...

Many thanks...

Comment: I believe for this question to adhere to stackoverflow's policies you need to narrow down the scope. There a many many ways this could be possible. What solution have you attempted so far?

Comment: We've been looking at PHP with imap (not got this working properly), or some other integration service (e.g. Zapier) which sends email details to a web page though a POST request. 

I'm not sure if either of these are the best ways though, and there may be something better out there.  Google some sort of Google Mail API link-up do this perhaps.  Or should we be using something more substantive than PHP (e.g Python) to do this?  Are there any other options?

Comment: I still believe this is too much of an opinion question, for example PHP and Python both are widely used and both could be used to complete this task. If you posted what you had attempted with PHP and imap and what issues you were seeing that would be a more appropriate question for the stackoverflow format.

Comment: I am indeed looking for opinions and implementation options though, which will help give a steer in the right direction...

Comment: This looks interesting. Waiting for answers. :)